# Horizontal Dropdown Menu on Adobe Business Catalyst website

Tags: html, css, adobe, business-catalyst

We currently have a Horizontal Menu on our website (http://www.faa.net.au) but I want to expand on this by making it a dropdown menu (up to 3 levels down) so I can remove the need for a left side menu, allowing me to maximise the web space for the content.

I have created a Test Template and Web Page so I am not working on the Live Site, the test page is here - http://www.faa.net.au/test/horizontal-menu

```
#cat_1418985_divs {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    clear: both;
    }
........
```

I have also created a JSFiddle page with "some" of the menu items I am trying to get working: https://jsfiddle.net/zvcgqyqx/3/

Comment: As my website is running with "Modules", I am not sure how best to display the code in JSFiddle. I have added what I have on my website but it wont display correctly obviously so its more for the CSS I have at present - https://jsfiddle.net/zvcgqyqx/

Comment: you could build a minimal example of it. don't need to be the whole project

Comment: I have updated the JSFiddle with the menu structure copied from the source code but removed a chunk and replaced the page links with hashtags. Hopefully this helps??

https://jsfiddle.net/zvcgqyqx/3/

Comment: I am not asking it for me, its to improve your question and let it easier to  other users help you so I believe you should post this fiddle on the question besides on the comments;

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Adobe Business Catalyst, but this code will get you a drop down menu.

**HTML**

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbutton">Resources</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">This is a link</a>
    <a href="#">So is this</a>
    <a href="#">And this, also</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.dropbutton {
    background-color: #000000;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I came up with for a client site I'm working on where they wanted to still use the Menu feature, but needed it to be dynamic and work with Bootstrap / BC Liquid. It will go up to 3 levels deep, based on the Menu you setup.

PAGE CODE

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar"> 
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> 
        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
        <img src="/images/logo.png" alt="">
    </a> 
  </div>
  <div class="topbarContact navbar-right">
    <span class="topPhone">(555) 555-5555</span> 
    <span class="topPipe">|</span> 
    <span class="topAddress">123 Main Street, City ST 12345</span> 
    <span class="topPipe">|</span> 
    <span class="topHours">Mon-Fri 8a-5p</span> 
    <span class="topSocial">
        <img src="/images/facebook.png" alt=""/>
        <img src="/images/twitter.png" alt=""/>
        <img src="/images/linkedin.png" alt=""/>
    </span>
  </div>
  <br />
  <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse"> 
    {module_menu render="collection" menuId="1234567" template="" collection="TopBar_NavRight"}
    <ul id="main-menu" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      {% if TopBar_NavRight.items %} 
      {% for i in TopBar_NavRight.items %}
      {% if i.items %}
      <li class="dropdown"> 
        <a href="{{i.url}}" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> 
            {{i.label}} <span class="caret"></span> 
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          {% for j in i.items %}
          <li><a href="{{j.url}}" >{{j.label}}</a></li>
          {% endfor %}
        </ul>
      </li>
      {% else %}
      <li><a href="{{i.url}}" >{{i.label}}</a> </li>
      {% endif %}
      {% endfor %} 

      {% endif %} 

      <!-- IF LOGGED IN ------ --> 
      {% if globals.user.isLoggedIn contains "true" %}
      <li><a href="/members_dashboard">Member Area</a> <span class="caret"></span></li>
      {% else %}
      <li><a href="/login">Member Login</a></li>
      {% endif %}
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

**CSS**
Using standard bootstrap CSS

**UPDATES**
You will need to update the menuID= item to match the ID of your menu.

**NOTES**
This is a two-line navigation setup with contact info, address, social links on top and navigation on the bottom. In addition is has a toggle button for if the user is logged in or not it changes the very last button to either login or go to member dashboard.

**DEMO**
This site is currently being built (not all links work yet, but it's all up so you can see it)... but you can see a sample of the nav in action here:  [www.goconifer.com/index-new](http://www.goconifer.com/index-new)

Hope this helps!